# A Fantasy Novel Involving a Vengeful Dead God Brought Back to Life from a Soul Well

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am hoping to learn the title of fantasy novel from the late 1980s/early 1990s.  The story begins with a god at odds with his own divine son.  The father figure condemns his son to an eternity trapped in a type of "soul well."  After thousands of years, three adventurers--two men and a woman--rescue the dead god.  They hope to harness his hatred for the father in their own search for treasure and glory.  These three also reunite the son with a special two-handed sword, the only weapon that can slay his father.  The story ends with one of the adventurers utilizing this great sword to slay a fearsome beast.  However, they no longer have a way of slaying the father, who, at that moment, is awakening from his own slumber.

Thank you for any help in tracking down this book.